# div content is clipped from bottom of the webpage

Tags: php, html, css

If you scroll down on https://jsfiddle.net/rtvrueg9/ you can see that some of the content at the bottom is not showing. any suggestions?

```
<?php include 'head.php';?>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of position fixed in your body, i added overflow-x: hidden; instead of that to remove horizontal scroll bar.

If that vertical horizontal bar bothers you remove unnessary overflow-y in .content
                                                    }

```css
body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
         overflow-x: hidden;  /* EDIT */
     }      
        h1 {
      font-family: arial;
      color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
      text-align: center; 
      margin: 0;
     }      
     header {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30%;
      background: black;
      background-image: url(profile_pic.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right;
      background-size: 20% 70%;
      color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
      text-align: center;
      border-spacing: 5px 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
     nav {
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      height: 25px;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
      border: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
     }
     .nav_link {
      flex-grow: 1;
      line-height: 25px;
     }
     a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
     }
     a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
     }
     .content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow-y:scroll;    }
     .myPanel {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 999;
      width: 60%;
      margin: 1% auto;
     }
     .myPanel .heading {
      background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 20px;
     }
     .myPanel .panelTime {
      padding: 3px 20px;
      background: silver;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
     }
     .myPanel p {
      margin: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
     }
     .myPanel:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
     }
     .myPanel.heading:hover {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
      color: black;
      font-family: arial;
     }
     .myPanel.panelTime:hover {
      background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
      font-family: arial;
      color: white;
     }
```

```html
<?php include 'head.php';?>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Resume</h1>
 </header>
 <nav>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="index.php"> Home </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="resume.php"> Resume </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="sideprojects.php"> Side Projects </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="aboutme.php"> About Me </a>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">US ARMY NATIONAL GUARD</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
    <p>03/2014 -- Current</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
       <p>Crystal River, FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Rank: PV2</ui></br>
        <ui>Diesel Mechanic -- 91H</ui></br>
        <ui>Military Police -- 31b<ui></br>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
       <p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui></br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui></br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui></br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui></br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui></br>
        <ui>Food running</ui></br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui></br>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">PANE D'OR</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
     <p>08/2015 -- 06/2016</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
       <p>Winter Garden FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Baking</ui></br>
        <ui>Pastry</ui></br>
        <ui>Delivering</ui></br>
        <ui>Sales at markets / shop</ui></br>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">Disney</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
     <p>06/2015 -- 11/2016</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
       <p>Orlando FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Monorail pilot</ui></br>
        <ui>Platform operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Audience control</ui></br>
        <ui>Customer relations</ui></br>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">PERFORMANCE YEARS GTO</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
     <p>01/2012 -- 02/2015</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
      
       <p>Hatfield PA</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Shipping</ui></br>
        <ui>Receiving</ui></br>
        <ui>Pulling/packing/sorting</ui></br>
        <ui>Picker operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Forklift operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Customer service</ui></br>
        <ui>In house sales</ui></br>
        <ui>Show sales</ui></br>
        <ui>Inventory</ui></br>
       </ul>
      
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">GIANT FOODS</div>
    <div class="panelTime">
     <p>01/2012 -- 03/2013</p>
     <div class="panelBody">
       <p>Montgomeryville PA</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Stocking shelves</ui></br>
        <ui>Rotate merchandise</ui></br>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: okay so this fixes the scroll bar to reach the bottom but it breaks my header now and my img is now to small

Comment: EDIT: okay so i changed my height of header from 30% to 25vh and it is working way better

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php include_once("head.php"); ?>
```

be sure the head.php file is in the same directory of your html file, also your htlm file should be renamed from index.html to index.php with the php extension